# Eclipse (Juno) Plugin: CDT does not work properly

Tags: eclipse, plugins, c++

I installed CDT plugin for Eclipse **Juno**, but I can't create new C++ projects in eclipse. I tried re-installing it. I also tried executing:

```
eclipse -initialize
```

in the folder containing **eclipse.exe** file and in the folder containing the **plugins**

It still does not work. What is the solution?

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Please enter your question title in this [search field](http://stackexchange.com/search)
and after seeing the results you decide if your question is valid.

Comment: I corrected the grammar.

Comment: | [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/538939/edit) | ... I did not say just for the error, I said because there are hundreds of questions similar to yours and if you are not clear, and does not favor more details
your question just looks like another one. and will be difficult for the community  help you, and many others users could downvote your question

Comment: Well, I read most of the posts. The solution they got was, using (eclipse -initialize). BUT, that solution does not work in my case.

Comment: Never mind. I just downloaded ADT-bundle which includes eclipse (java and c++) and android sdk.